# Write in specific kafka partition in apache beam with Kafka Connector

Tags: python-3.x

I have been working on a POC for the company i'm working for and Im using apache beam kafka connector to read from kafka topic and write into other kafka topic. The source and target topic have 3 partitions and is compulsory keep ordering by certain message keys. Regarding it I have two questions:

1. How can I write an specific message to an specific kafka partition.
2. How can we commit the message to the source topic only and only when the pipeline had processed the message.

I looking forward and hope you can help me with these doubts.

I have using co mmit_on_finalize option